# How to use Oracle Connection pooling using PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, connection, pooling

I am using PHP with Oracle Database 12c and i want to implement connection pooling for improve my application performance
Can you help me please ?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: well, i tried this example https://workwiththebest.intraway.com/blog-post/performance-oracle-pool-with-php/, but it's showing TNS error only when i put this :POOLED string after service name

Answer (score 1):

Check the Database Resident Connection Pooling (DRCP) chapter of Oracle's free [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).

First determine if you need DRCP.  I assume you are already using persistent `oci_pconnect()` calls, which is the first thing to do to improve connection performance.

Like any pool, DRCP is a shared resource so there is some overhead and you need to make sure that connections are not held open which would block other users.  If you're not running out of memory on the DB server host, I would suggest not using it.

If you decide to try it, the basic steps are:

- start the pool, something like

  ```
  SQL> execute dbms_connection_pool.start_pool()
  ```
- update your php.ini and set a connection class:

  ```
  oci8.connection_class = MYPHPAPP
  ```
- Use a pooled connect string like

  ```
  $c = oci_pconnect('myuser', 'mypassword', 'myhost/sales:POOLED');
  ```

  or

  ```
  $c = oci_pconnect('myuser', 'mypassword', 'salespool');
  ```

  where the connect alias is in a tnsnames.ora file:

  ```
  salespool=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)
  (HOST=myhost.dom.com)
    (PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sales)
  (SERVER=POOLED)))
  ```

Comment: currently, I am using "oci_connect", So if oci_pconnect is better than oci_connect than should I change it to oci_pcoonect first instead of connection pooling technique?

Comment: Just letting you know my DB server configuration is very good enough.

Comment: Yes, use oci_pconnect() first.  Make sure that your number of mid-tier PHP processes is as small as possible (don't oversize the number), since each will now keep a DB connection open.  Each of these will take some memory on the DB host.